# Automatically changing the state of a workitem in TFS 2012, when changes are done to fields

Tags: tfs

how to implement a state change in TFS 2012, when any fields are changed in that work item type.

I have a task work item type which is set to "proposed". When the field/fields are changed in task work item, state should be changed to "Active" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the work item definition and add a rule to the field. Refer to this link for details: [Working with Field Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Assign Conditional-Based Values and Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194966(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Depending on the data type of a field, you can set various
>   restrictions on what data can be entered into that field. For example,
>   you can define a default value, restrict what values users can
>   specify, and restrict who can update the value of the field. You may
>   want to apply a rule to a work item field for one or more of the
>   following reasons:
>
> - Specify the tooltip text that appears when a user hovers over a field    in a work item form.
> - Require the value of a string field to match a pattern.
> - Make a field required or read-only, or make sure that it does not    contain the same value as another field.
> - Clear a field, or restrict further modifications of a field.
> - Restrict who can modify the field.
> - Apply a rule to a field when the value of another field has changed    or is assigned a specific value.

**Update:**
For System fields, there is some restriction for them. Refer to this link for details: [Q: What rules can be applied to System fields?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx#Anchor_5)

> Q: What rules can be applied to System fields? A: System fields have
>   Sytem.Name reference names, for example System.Title and System.State.
>   TFS restricts customization of these fields, except for these
>   instances: HELPTEXT rule can be assigned to all fields. READONLY rule
>   can be assigned to the State and Reason fields. Most rules can be
>   assigned to the Title, Assigned To, Description or Changed By System
>   fields.

That means, you cannot apply the rule to change the state in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your post @Eddie-MSFT, so i have to set the rule for each and every field that`s accessible to the users now, if i get your post right.

Comment: @alm5599 I just check your question again and found that you are trying to add a rule to System.State which is restricted by TFS. Please see my updated answer for details. Sorry for didn't point it out before.